# I want to write a compiler; what assembly(x86)/backend do you recommend? uses BISON or no?

Tags: parsing, assembly, compiler-construction, code-generation, bison

I'm writing a very simple and small compiler(by my own, I'm not doing course or anything). And I need a help to make some decisions. The first step(I believe), I need to know about assembly to code generation(right?). I'm looking for the *better* assembly language for it. Better in the sense of easy to do coding/understand good back-end support etc. I have read the [`HOWTO assembly by LPD`](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Assembly-HOWTO/) where there is several assemblies; but I'm really interested in do AT&T code generation. By the fact that I'm familiar to GNU/Linux, GCC and GCC-like compilers that do AT&T code generation.

do you have other suggestions? if possible explain the advantages on AT&T syntax and back-end(if any).

for a person which never have written a compiler before, too complex to do it without BISON or equivalent? I want to do it by using [`recursive descent parser`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser)(as e.g, DMR and gcc 4.6>, and TCC does).  Also, as it's my first compiler(for non-basic-like and with assembly), I have in my mind that's wrong do it with BISON help.

Tnanks very much.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered writing it to the JVM?  It exists on your platform and (I presume?) will be easier to work with than raw machine ASM.

Comment: Good suggestion, but I just want to put it out there that there are a lot of other VMs too: LLVM, .NET, Parrot (I think), JVM, Mono, C-- (Only code generation).

Comment: Thanks very much for suggestion. But I want to really convert it to machine code. :)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, AT&T vs. Intel is *just* a matter of syntax. The underlying platforms capabilities are determined by the hardware architecture, not by the syntax. If you want your compiler to be portable, you need to support multiple architectures, but the syntax you use can stay the same. If you use AT&T syntax, you will still have to generate different code for x86 and ARM. There is only one assembly language for each architecture. For example, here's adding two numbers first in Intel and then in AT&T:

```
mov eax, 1
mov ebx, 2
add eax, ebx
```

And:

```
movl $1, %eax
movl $2, %ebx
addl %ebx, %eax
```

Comment: I know that. Actually, I'm looking for another suggestions, e.g: yesterday I met  HLA and terse. I'm considering do NASM or FLAT code generation instead of AT&T.

Comment: @Jack: I agree. I find Intel syntax much cleaner than AT&T. The only thing is, if you want to use AT&T, you use GAS, and for Intel, you use NASM.

Answer (score 1):

[antlr](http://www.antlr.org/) is another package worth looking into, i find it easier to use than flex and bison. It also comes with an editor which makes the process even easier. You can use it to generate parsers for multiple languages, flex and bison is c/c++ based. You also define the syntax and parse rules in one file when using antlr, with flex and bison you have to create .l and a .y/.ypp files which can get really confusing when it comes to know what to put in each.

I dont know much about assembly, but there's a free course at [Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/) about compilers that teaches about parsing code and compiling it down to assebly. check it out